# how to create a sliding menu which will fill the window width except by puller button width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a sliding menu which will fill the window width minus the puller button width. I want the menu out of the window when web page load and there is a button which will go left when the page loads. When user clicks on the button the menu should come to window and button goes right.
I have created an  [animation video here](http://wideo.co/view/12657661454823403813-slide?from=cp&utm_source=CopyPaste&utm_medium=share&utm_campaign=player) which will show you what I want.

In the jsfiddle the menu just fades out, But I want the menu to slide from left to right when clicked on button with `.puller` class.

See the code at jsfiddle
Demo on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tutsooos/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var stickyNavTop = ($('.container')).offset().top;

  var stickyNav = function(){
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scrollTop > stickyNavTop) { 
      $('.container').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
      $('.container').removeClass('fixed');
    }
  };

  stickyNav();

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    stickyNav();
  }).resize(function() {
    stickyNav();
  }).load(function() {
    stickyNav();
  });
  $(".dropdown").click(function() {
    $(".dpitem").slideToggle(300);
  });
  var calcWidth = function() {
    var pullerDimensions = $('.puller').width();
    $('#cpcc,.dpitem').width($(window).width() - pullerDimensions);
  }
  $(document).ready(function() {
    calcWidth();
  });

  $(window).resize(function() {
    calcWidth();
  }).load(function() {
    calcWidth();
  });
  var cPcc = document.getElementById ("cpcc");

  var cpHeight = function() {
    var cpBtnHolder = $(cPcc).height();
    $('.content').css("padding-top",cpBtnHolder);
  }

  setInterval(function() {
    cpHeight();
    calcPHeight();
    pp();
  }, 0)
  var calcPHeight = function() {
    var toolsDimensions = $('#cpcc').height();
    $('.puller').height(toolsDimensions);
    $('.puller').css("line-height",toolsDimensions +"px");
  }
  $(document).ready(function() {
    calcPHeight();
  });
  $(window).resize(function() {
    calcPHeight();
  }).load(function() {
    calcPHeight();
  });
  var Pwidth = $('#cpcc').width();
  var PSpce = $(window).width()-Pwidth;
  $(".puller").click(function() {
    $(".container").toggle( function() {
      $(".container").css({
        transform: "translate3d("+"-"+Pwidth+"px, 0, 0)"
      });
    }, function () {
      $(".container").css({
        transform: "translate3d(-0, 0, 0)"
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see how and what to ask. There is a good reason SO does not like links to jsfiddle without code here too. What is the actual question?

Comment: In jsfiddle the menu just fade out But I want the menu slide from left to right when clicked on button with .puller class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calc is your friend. You can use that along with 'transition' to achieve the intended effect. Check out this simplified example.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gPBQOb

Good practice is to toggle a class which will override the position property in this case left. It should also toggle your chevron image to point left and right.

Your example is using a lot of js calculations and has to recalculate with window size changes. This example uses js only to toggle a css class on click and the rest in managed purely with css. Much simpler in my opinion.

#### HTML

```
<div class="maincontent"></div>
<div class="menu">
  <div class="button"></div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.maincontent{
  background-color: green;
  height: 2000px;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu{
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  transition: left 1s;
}

.menu.collapse{
  left: calc(-100% + 30px)
}

.button{
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100%;
  width: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
}
```

#### JS

```
$('.button').click(
  function(){
    $('.menu').toggleClass('collapse')
  })
```